# Connecting to Raspberrypi from external network

Tags: nat, dynamic-dns, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi and a 2TB NAS attached to it. My ISP sets a dynamic IP address every time I log in to it but I am behind a NAT that gives me a private IP address instead of a public one. My goal is to set up syncthing that I can access from external network. Since I get a private IP, using dynamic DNS providers like noip is not an option for me. How can I set a static IP (or domain) to the RPI in order to access it from external network?

Comment: Are you sure? I [read](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=662104) otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I have good news and bad news.

#### Good news

You can set static IP (or domain) to your Raspberry Pi.

#### Bad news

It won't do you much good, since you still won't be able to access it from outside your network. This is because you are behind NAT (could more than one NAT too) and your router (or whatever you have) doesn't have public IP address.

You should ask your ISP if it's possible for you to have a public IP or if they could port forward the services you require. Make sure you get it working with your IP address first, then add DDNS to the mix. After that you are good to go.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the good news?

Comment: Yes, certainly. The good news aren't actually good news. More like neutral news. Anyway, you can set up your Raspberry Pi with whatever static IP you want from the private address space, but that doesn't make it any easier contact your RPI from external networks. You can also set a domain name for the RPI, but it'll only work in your private network. Your ISP controls the connections from external networks to yours, and most likely all ports are closed. That means it's a no go for any connections coming in to your network. That's why you need to contact your ISP.